# Show discontinuity with $\epsilon-\delta$

Tags: inequality, continuity, epsilon-delta

I want to use the $\epsilon-\delta$-criterion to show that for any $c\in\mathbb R$ the function
$$
f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, x\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}, &x\neq 0 \\
c, & x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous.

Let $x = 0$.
Then we have
$$
\mid f(x) - f(0)\mid
=
\mid\frac{1}{x} - c\mid
=
\mid \frac{1-xc}{x}\mid
=
\mid \frac{cx-1}{x} \mid
=
\frac{\mid cx-1 \mid }{\mid x \mid}.
$$
From triangle inequality we have
$$
\frac{\mid cx-1 \mid }{\mid x \mid}
\leq
\frac{\mid cx\mid +1 }{\mid x \mid}
=
\frac{\mid c\mid \cdot \mid x-0\mid +1 }{\mid x \mid}
\leq
\frac{\mid c\mid \cdot \delta +1 }{\mid x \mid}
$$
But how can I get rid of the denominator?
If I can't, what is an argument that it is not possible?

Comment: "Let $x = 0$": don't you rather mean "Let $x\ne0$"?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would to be argue by sequential definition of continuity. If we can find a sequence ${x_n}\to 0$ but $f(x_n)\not\to f(0)=c$ then we're done. But if you pick the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ , that converges to zero , but $f(x_n)\rightarrow +\infty$ . Therefore, not continuous at $x=0$, we're done because we found such a sequence.

But if your hand is forced on $\epsilon - \delta$
I think the error in your method comes from trying to estimate $|f(x)-f(0)|$ from above: Really , if you are proving discontinuity, surely you want to try and bound it from below?

Remember , the definition of being discontinuous at $x=0$ is that:

$$\exists \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0 , \exists x \text{ s.t. } |x|<\delta \text{ but } |f(x)-f(0)|\ge \epsilon$$

Comment: Yes that's how it must be done.